# Archive::Zip, EBook::Epub, and IIS6 - "desiredCompressionLevel" error

Tags: perl, iis-6, zip, epub

I'm trying to convert html files to epub with EBook::Epub. The script I've written is very simple, like so:

```
my $epub = EBook::EPUB->new;
$epub->add_title('title');
$epub->add_author('author');
$epub->add_language('en');
$epub->copy_xhtml("d:/path/to/file.html" , "file.html");
$epub->pack_zip("d:/path/to/file.epub");
```

When I run this from the command line, it works great. However, I'm trying to deploy it as a CGI script on an IIS6 server--which runs off the *same* computer--it fails with this message:

```
Can't call method "desiredCompressionLevel" on an undefined value at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 252.
```

I checked out Archive.pm, and line 252 is in sub addFile. It's using three variables--$fileName, $newName, $compressionLevel--and I used some print statements to reveal their values from right before line 252. ($compressionLevel is always blank)

This is from the command line, which works:

```
filename: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\7QiqzzNiN5/OPS/file.html 
newname: OPS/Advanced8247.html
filename: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\7QiqzzNiN5/OPS/content.opf 
newname: OPS/content.opf
filename: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\7QiqzzNiN5/OPS/toc.ncx 
newname: OPS/toc.ncx
filename: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\DkgiQN_pTq 
newname: META-INF/container.xml
```

This is from the server, which bombs:

```
filename: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\8rxbvOVkKy/OPS/file.html 
newname: OPS/Advanced6575.html
filename: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\8rxbvOVkKy/OPS/content.opf 
newname: OPS/content.opf
filename: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\8rxbvOVkKy/OPS/toc.ncx 
newname: OPS/toc.ncx
filename: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\WqS7fskWi0 
newname: META-INF/container.xml
```

So I'm guessing that my problem has to do with where the temp files are being written, but I really don't know enough about servers and Archive::Zip to figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the temp directory being written to is writable by the IIS user that IIS runs as (IIS_IUSRS and/or IUSR).  When you run on the commandline, you're running as a different user which probably has permissions to write to C:\Windows\Temp.  I had a similar problem (writing to that same temp dir) and was able to fix the issue by change the temp directory to something more local to the published document root of my web app which already had the correct permissions under Properties > Security.

In my situation, I was able to set the environment variable, TMPDIR, in my script:

```
$ENV{TMPDIR} = 'C:\Inetpub\tmp'
```

and the folder permissions for C:\Inetpub\tmp were updated to be writable by IIS_IUSRS and IUSR.

Here's a snippet from [http://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip](http://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aZip) that talks about temp files and setting $ENV{TMPDIR}

```
Archive::Zip::tempFile( [$tmpdir] )

Create a uniquely named temp file. It will be returned open for read/write. If $tmpdir
is given, it is used as the name of a directory to create the file in. If not given, 
creates the file using File::Spec::tmpdir(). Generally, you can override this choice
using the

    $ENV{TMPDIR}

environment variable. But see the File::Spec documentation for your system. Note that 
on many systems, if you're running in taint mode, then you must make sure that 
$ENV{TMPDIR} is untainted for it to be used. Will NOT create $tmpdir if it doesn't 
exist (this is a change from prior versions!). Returns file handle and name:

    my ($fh, $name) = Archive::Zip::tempFile();
    my ($fh, $name) = Archive::Zip::tempFile('myTempDir');
    my $fh = Archive::Zip::tempFile();  # if you don't need the name
```